# How to Auto close side drop down menu when other menu is opened

Tags: html

I have created sidebar drop down menu using some html code as shown in below given jsfiddle. This code is working fine. It opens all the drop down menu perfectly. But it does not auto close previous opened drop down menus. I want to auto close previous opened drop down menus whenever new menu is opened. Kindly help me in doing this. Thanks in advance.

```
<style>
 summary::-webkit-details-marker {
 display: none;
}
summary:focus {
    outline-style: none;
}
article > details > summary {
    display: block;
    padding: 7px 10px 8px;
    font-family: "proximanova-light","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 10px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: relative;
background-color: #428bca;
}


article > details > summary:hover {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: relative;
background-color: #39b3d7;
}

details > p {
    margin-left: 24px;
}
details details {
    margin-left: 36px;
}
details details summary {
    font-size: 14px;
}

</style>





    <div class="sidebar">



<span class="title">Dashboard</span>
    <section>
      <article>

        <details>
          <summary>Advertisers<span class="fa fa-caret-down pull-right fa-lg" style="margin-top: 3px;padding-right:5px;"></span></summary>
            <ul class="sidenav">
    <li class="account "><a href="/advertisers"><em>Overview</em></a></li>
    <li class="settings "><a href="/advertisers/myads"><em>My Ads</em></a></li>
    <li class="settings "><a href="/advertisers/mywaitlist"><em>My Wait List</em></a></li>
    <li class="settings "><a href="/buy"><em>Buy Ads</em></a></li>
    <li class="payment "><a href="/advertisers/mystats"><em>Ad Stats</em></a></li>
    <li class="payment "><a href="/advertisers/approvals"><em>Ad Approvals</em></a></li>
    <li class="separator"></li>
        </ul>
        </details>
      </article>

      <article>
        <details>
          <summary>Account<span class="fa fa-caret-down pull-right fa-lg" style="margin-top: 3px;padding-right:5px;"></span></summary>
            <ul class="sidenav">
    <li class="settings "><a href="/users/account"><em>My Profile</em></a></li>
    <li class="deposit"><a href="/cart/deposit"><em>Deposit Funds</em></a></li>
    <li class="transactions"><a href="/users/transactions"><em>Transactions</em></a></li>
        </ul>
          </details>
      </article> 

</section>


</div>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/nL74z9r9/)